# Xlsxread returns empty cells when the column is not empty

Tags: excel, matlab, import, xlsx

I'm trying to walk my way through someone else's script, and I'm having an issue right at the import. I've read some documentation files but I can't seem to find the answer.

This import syntax returns a mostly empty cell array. The first row, which is a text header, is imported correcly. Some cells are imported correctly, but they are very sparse (the first is row 133, the second row 216)

```
[~,x1] = xlsread(speaker1, 'B:B');
```

For reference, this other command works fine.

```
[~,times1] = xlsread(speaker1, 'A:A');
```

I'm attaching the head of the excel sheet.

```
Time    F0   Voicing_prob     Energy
1.79  112.734   0.0253772   -412.686
1.8   158.389   0.0266182   -418.459
1.81  149.288   0.0246      -417.709
1.82  102.087   0.0204231   -397.856
1.83  615.066   0.0204416   -303.539
1.84  606.881   0.0266568   -280.339
1.85  671.306   0.0237999   -276.029
1.86  139.161   0.0331053   -269.168
1.87  138.115   0.0570455   -232.405
1.88  137.589   0.0724696   -197.474
1.89  138.115   0.0814753   -182.539
```

If a bigger data sample is needed just let me know. I would also appreciate a hint on how to easily provide large datasets, instead of copy-pastying and re-formatting.

Comment: The second output of `xslread` is `txt`. From the docs: Text data, returned as a cell array. Numeric values in inner spreadsheet rows and columns appear as empty character vectors, ' ', in txt. Read the docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#btg5vmt-1-txt

Comment: Thank you, I will. Do you have any idea why the import works on the Time column? They are both numeric. Further, row 133 and 216 are imported correctly and are both numeric.

Comment: Read again the docs and specifically the part I posted. **inner  spreadsheet rows and columns**

Comment: Sorry, I obviously misread, that does answer my question about the correct Time import. However, I still don't understand why I have some correct import for the F0 cell (they are numbers), and why it worked for the person that provided the code (they showed me the on their laptop, it run smoothly).

Comment: Do they have the same version of MATLAB?

Comment: They do. I will try getting in touch with them once they are back from their holidays, if I cannot solve the issues beforehand.

Comment: I can't your xls file in the post.